# MAXINT overflow in C

Tags: c

When defining a max integer variable I get an error:

`overflow in expression; result is 2147483647 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]`

line in the code:

`const int MAXINT = (1 << (8*sizeof(int)-1))-1;`

used language: C
cpu: 64bit (code maybe written in 32bit machine)

please, what should to do?

Comment: Use `1L` instead of `1` in `1<<`.

Comment: C has a builtin `INT_MAX` constant.

Comment: You can just use `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.

Comment: @FUZxxl That won't help if long is the same size as int.

Comment: @Reda: This solves the error only on some 64-bit platforms. `long` often isn't wider than `int`.

Comment: In this case, use `1LL` instead.

Comment: Why not just use the (fully portable) features the language provides and readers of the code are expecting? (If I see `INT_MAX`, I know what it is, if I see `MAXINT` I have to look for the definition.)

Comment: Rather than subtract 1 (after overflow occurred): `((1 << (8*sizeof(int)-2))-1)*2 + 1`.

Comment: @mafso :) you're absolutely right, but it's an old source code and I have to compile it.

Comment: @chux: tempting to say 'use CHAR_BIT instead of 8' but then you'd need `<limits.h>` and then you'd have `INT_MAX` so you'd use that to initialize MAXINT.  You beat me to the expression by a few seconds.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Sometimes one could have [Missed it by that much](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Get_Smart).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overflow potentially occurs here

```
(1 << (8*sizeof(int)-1))
```

Rather than subtract 1 (after overflow occurred):

```
const int MAXINT = ((1 << (8*sizeof(int)-2))-1)*2 + 1
```

Note: better to use `CHAR_BIT` than `8`.  But then that typically brings in `INT_MAX` (@Jonathan Leffler ) and code could use (@mafso)

```
const int MAXINT = INT_MAX;
```

Comment: As a (slightly easier to read IMO) alternative, `(1u << CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1) - 1`. Further suggest removing "potentially", as it always shifts into the sign bit (if not further, because of padding bits; but I think, handcrafting INT_MAX is impossible to do portably across implementations with possible padding bits). (And while you're at it, the second snippet could get a terminating semicolon `;` and you can remove the contribution to me if you like.)